# CloneDeep causing issues in scroller

Tags: angular, lodash

I have just dived into **Angular**, so some of the terminology may be a bit off.
But I am trying to obtain an object from my `store$` which is basically an array of objects(search results) and modify it.

In order to avoid an 'object is not extensible error' I've used `cloneDeep from **lodash**.
However this gives me an unusual error where the scroll bar automatically scrolls to the bottom and activates infinite search. This keeps sending queries for newer results.

I've tried messing around with my scroll function which moves the scroller 0.7 to the top such that infinite scroll is not constantly activated when the scroller moves to the bottom.

However, I am clueless as to why `cloneDeep` is causing issues with the scroller. I am not even sure what I should be looking into.

```
//piping

this.resultSet$ = this.store$.pipe(
        select(SearchIndexQuery.getIndexResultSet, { id: <string>this.searchIndex, resultSetId: this.id }),
        map(resultSet => {
         finalResult = cloneDeep(resultSet);
          //do something to the resultSet
         finalResult.data = someFunc(finalResult.data)       
        })
      );

//scroller
if (this.currentRows > this.NUM_SEARCH_ROWS && this.selectElement.panel) {
            const panel = this.selectElement.panel.nativeElement;
            panel.scrollTop = 0.7 * (panel.scrollHeight - panel.offsetHeight);
          }
```

without `cloneDeep` the search box behaves as expected (however I cannot modify the object otherwise)
with `cloneDeep` the scroller starts showing unexpected behavior